# jquery ui autocomplete select menu html entities (ampersand and quotes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, entity

I am trying to get html entities such as ampersands & and quotes ' ' to appear in a jquery ui autocomplete menu.

I was able to override the _renderItem method to fix the display in the menu, but when an item is seleted the encoded characters still appear in the input

how would I go about fixing the display in the input field itself?

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gq2F6/2/

thanks

js code here:

```
var autocomplete_items = [{label:'fish &amp; chips',value:'fish&amp;chips',id:'01'},{label:'food',value:'food',id:'02'}];

var $keywords = $('#keywords');

$keywords.autocomplete({
    minLength:2,
    source: autocomplete_items
});

$keywords.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item){
    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append($("<a></a>").html(item.value)).appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Why doesn't this work? http://jsfiddle.net/Gq2F6/3/

Comment: The fiddle is a minimal test case. In the actual application, I can't control the array of strings passed in as source. label: and value: end up always being the same with the html entities encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gq2F6/4/

```
var autocomplete_items = [{label:'fish &amp; chips',value:'fish&amp;chips',id:'01'},{label:'food',value:'food',id:'02'}];

var decodeEntities = (function() {
  // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
  var element = document.createElement('div');

  function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      // strip script/html tags
      str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
      str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }

  return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();


var $keywords = $('#keywords');

$keywords.autocomplete({
   minLength:2,
   source: autocomplete_items,
   select: function (e, ui) {
      $keywords.val(decodeEntities(ui.item.value));
      return false;
   }
});

$keywords.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item){
   return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append($("<a></a>").html(item.value)).appendTo(ul);
};
```

It uses the autocomplete's select event to override what happens when you click on one of the returned items. Instead of just doing the default copy of the value to the input field, it first decodes the HTML entities. (It's better to decode the entities like that, rather than use jQuery's .text() when you might have untrusted data).

Comment: That works great for the select event! When I use the arrow keys to move through the list it doesn't run the decodeEntities function. I don't think there is a autocomplete ui event for that though.